# Xamarin Forms Picker control opens when entering input in Entry control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

For reproducing the problem, I have added 2 controls to a content page: Picker and Entry. The container is a TableView section.

If I click on the Entry control, causing the keyboard to open, or enter characters in it, the Picker selection is opening. It's opening every time I enter a character or removing one (so when the value is changing).

I don't have this problem if the main container isn't a TableView, but for example a StackLayout.

I have this problem since Xamarin Forms v3.3. In previous versions, like 3.2, this problem didn't exist. The problem also exists in the 3.4 beta.

Also: the problem only occurs in Android (version 4 - 9). Not in iOS.

Below you'll find my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PickerBugXF33"
         x:Class="PickerBugXF33.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
    <TableView x:Name="testTableView" Intent="Form" HasUnevenRows="true" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PickerBugXF33
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            testTableView.Root = new TableRoot();

            var section = new TableSection("Test section");
            testTableView.Root.Add(section);

            var viewCell = new ViewCell();
            section.Add(viewCell);

            var stack = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical };
            viewCell.View = stack;

            var picker = new Picker();
            picker.Items.Add("Test item in picker");

            stack.Children.Add(picker);

            var entry = new Entry();

            stack.Children.Add(entry);

        }
    } 
}
```

NB: This is a test project. The real live project is much larger in which the page has to be created via code.

Update 1, 11/9/2018: Might be solved by commit: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4344/commits/8401d81745ad248b5b70aa669863c8b8c8753e66

Comment: I try your code at my side , but I cannot reproduce your issue. The Picker control doesn’t open when I enter input something in Entry in Android 5.0.

Comment: @CherryBu Which version of XF did you use?

Comment: @CherryBu "I have this problem since Xamarin Forms v3.3. In previous versions, like 3.2, this problem didn't exist. The problem also exists in the 3.4 beta."

Comment: my xamarin.form version is v3.1.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xamarin.Forms v:3.3 and v:3.4,
I just installed v:3.2 and the issue is not there, 
thanks @John_ for solution